# Probability distribution over a variable? What does it mean?

Tags: distributions, density-function, definition

In this document [http://legacydirs.umiacs.umd.edu/~xyang35/files/understanding-variational-lower.pdf](https://web.archive.org/web/20180321063102/http://legacydirs.umiacs.umd.edu/%7Exyang35/files/understanding-variational-lower.pdf) at the very first page, it says:

Moreover, uppercase P(X) denotes the probability distribution over that variable, and
lowercase p(X) is the density function of the distribution of X.

I have never come across this distinction. Is it a common one? What does it really mean? Isn't the distribution over a variable the same as the density of that variable?

Comment: P(X) = Pr(X <= x)

Comment: P(X) is likely meant as the cumulative density function while p(X) is the density function. Except perhaps for degenerate cases, both contain the same information but in a different form.

Comment: ah, of course P(X) is the cumulative. Is it common to say that the cumulative is a "probability distribution over that variable"?

Comment: I would not say it, but some other people do: the cumulative distribution function does determine the distribution (at least for univariate random variables taking real values): if it has a derivative then you can take that to be the density function

Comment: I've also seen $P(X)$ used for the probability mass function for a discrete variable $X$, and $p(X)$ as the probability density function for a continuous variable $X$. Since the notes you linked don't actually use $P$ anywhere, it's difficult to guess the intended interpretation.